# What's the word that would mean left you "unanswerable"?

Tags: single-word-requests

My language has a word which has two meanings, one meaning means something close to unanswerable. i.e. two people are arguing and one counters with such a valid point that other one has been made "without an answer or response"

unanswerable doesn't seem to fit here. It sounds more right to say this question is unanswerable. Not you have been made unanswerable or he was left unanswerable.

Answerless.. is that word?

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus? Several of these words seem to fit: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unanswerable

Comment: If you're stuck for a good reply, you're speechless.

Comment: The verb could be confound, dumbfound, perplex, nonplus . . . These may have different connotations from what you want, but if you put them into a thesaurus you should get more options.

Comment: You can say that the counter/point was unanswerable. A lot of the synonyms above seem a bit broader - a person can be speechless/dumbfounded/etc for lots of reasons, including that the argument was so unbelievably *in*valid that it shocked the listener

Comment: How about *at a loss for words*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the expression “***[to be answerless](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/answerless)”***:

> not having or offering an answer.

(Collins Dictionary)

From: [A World Slowed: The Jared Chronicles](https://books.google.it/books?id=aufiDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA219&dq=%22was%20answerless%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjaw_Sz1PH4AhWO16QKHc4uAOUQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22was%20answerless%22&f=false)

> The old man usually had the answer, and here he was answerless.